# How to exclude and override some constraint from platform?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In our project, we use a central gradle bom module to manage version of all these dependencies.

To make life more easy, our gradle bom inherit from 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies' ([mvn repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.6.4)). And override version of some dependency in our own bom module.

Due to below issue in liquibase-core, we have to downgrade the version of liquibase-core in our bom module. **But an issue happened at here**.

[liquibase-issue-2586](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/2586)

The version of 'liquibase-core' works is '3.10.3'. But the one referred in 'spring-boot-dependencies' is '4.5.0'.

Below is the our *build.gradle*.

```
dependencies{
    // ...
    api platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.6.4")

    constraints {
        api ('org.liquibase:liquibase-core') {
            version {
                strictly '3.10.3'
            }
            because("The <property /> definition for column type doesn't work in version 4.6.1")
        // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then below compile error happened in these project based on above bom.

```
   > Could not resolve org.liquibase:liquibase-core:{strictly 3.10.3}.
     Required by:
         project :some-domain-service > xxx:app-frw-bom:0.20.x
      > Cannot find a version of 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'some-domain-service:unspecified' --> 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
           Constraint path 'some-domain-service:unspecified' --> 'xxx:app-frw-bom:0.20.x' --> 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:{strictly 3.10.3}' because of the following reason: The <property /> definition for column type doesn't work in version 4.6.1
           Constraint path 'some-domain-service:unspecified' --> 'xxx:app-frw-bom:0.20.x' --> 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.6.4' --> 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.5.0'
```

Below is the *build.gradle* of the domain-service. Just FYI.

```
dependencies{
    implementation platform("xxx:app-frw-bom:0.20.x")

    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using resolutionStrategy:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force('org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.10.3')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me (Gradle 8.1.1) to override a Spring Boot managed version in a Gradle platform:

```
dependencies {
  api(platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.6.4') {
    dependencies {
      api('org.liquibase:liquibase-core') { version { strictly '3.10.3' } }
    }
  })

  constraints {
    ...
  }
}
```